# constexpr with delegating constructors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have to following code:

```
class IP4Address
{
    public:
    constexpr IP4Address();
    constexpr IP4Address(uint32_t a_IP, uint16_t a_Port);

    private:
    uint32_t m_IP;
    uint16_t m_Port;
};

constexpr IP4Address::IP4Address():
    IP4Address(0, 0)
{

}

constexpr IP4Address::IP4Address(uint32_t a_IP, uint16_t a_Port):
    m_IP(a_IP),
    m_Port(a_Port)
{

}
```

Which results in the following errors (Visual Studio 2015):

```
error C2476: 'constexpr' constructor does not initialize all members
note: 'IP4Address::m_IP' was not initialized by the constructor
note: 'IP4Address::m_Port' was not initialized by the constructor
```

Is this invalid C++? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this possibly a compiler bug?

Comment: After changing `uint32` to `uint32_t` and `uint16` to `uint16_t`, it worked fine for me using g++ 4.9.3.

Comment: Maybe it is related to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/06/02/constexpr-complete-for-vs-2015-rtm-c-11-compiler-c-17-stl.aspx, citing: "I'm not aware of any constexpr bugs in the STL, but there are a few compiler bugs that remain to be fixed - notably DevDiv#1134662 "constexpr constructors are emitting dynamic initializers" and 1165072 "constexpr ICE with brace elision" in our internal database. "

Comment: After changing `uint32` to `uint32_t` and `uint16` to `uint16_t` I can reproduce in MSVC 2015 but not on g++(http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c22a7bd8d64ccc3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in MSVC 2015. The C++ 11 documentation `§7.1.5 4` says in a pretty clear manner:

> **4. The definition of a constexpr constructor shall satisfy the following constraints**:
>
> *4.1* the class shall not have any virtual base classes
>
> *4.2* each of the parameter types shall be a literal type
>
> *4.3* its function-body shall not be a function-try-block;
>
> In addition, either its function-body shall be = delete, or it shall satisfy the following constraints:
>
> *4.4* either its function-body shall be = default, or the compound-statement of its function-body shall satisfy the constraints for a function-body of a constexpr function;
>
> *4.5* every non-variant non-static data member and base class sub-object shall be initialized
>
> *4.6* if the class is a union having variant members (9.5), exactly one of them shall be initialized;
>
> *4.7* if the class is a union-like class, but is not a union, for each of its anonymous union members having variant members, exactly one of them shall be initialized;
>
> *4.8* for a non-delegating constructor, every constructor selected to initialize non-static data members and base class sub-objects shall be
>   a constexpr constructor;
>
> *4.9* for a delegating constructor, the target constructor shall be a constexpr constructor.

Your class matches all criterias. [Clang](http://goo.gl/IaZNDe) and [GCC](http://goo.gl/Cfv5Ax) also accept your source so I would be surprised if I overlooked something.